# How do I use the external IP of an ec2 instance in an ansible template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, infrastructure

I am configuring nodes that are in rackspace/digitalocean/aws/google cloud and need to access the external IP of the ec2 instances in a template in ansible.

I want to define my machines in the host file like this:

```
taps_1 ansible_host=54.123.456.789  dc=aws-richmond provider=aws
```

and then in a template (like one for iptables):

```
-A FWR -ieth0 -p tcp -s {{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }} --dport 80   -j ACCEPT
```

but that value doesn't exist :/ if I use the `ansible_fqdn` or the IP provided on the `ansible_default_ipv4` I only get the internal IP (e.g. `172.31.50.181`)

We have been defining our infra like this:

```
54.123.456.789 name=taps_1 dc=aws-richmond provider=aws
```

and accessing by doing `hostvars[host].inventory_name`, but I would like to not do that.

Ideas?

Comment: You're using static inventory files instead of [the provided dynamic inventory scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html)?  The Amazon one provides a whole host of variables to use.

Comment: We have stuff in aws/digitalocean/rackspace - we don't want to configure only using ec2 variables

Comment: You can use multiple dynamic inventory files by specifying a directory instead of a file, and merge groups together into one role.  That will definitely be a more scalable solution in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

In Ansible 1.9 you can use the `ansible_ssh_host` variable while on Ansible 2.0 you can use the `ansible_host`

In your template you just need to use this variable to get the public IP of your host and it will get it from your inventory file:

for example:
Ansible 1.9

```
{{ ansible_ssh_host }}
```

or
Ansible 2.0

```
{{ ansible_host }}
```

Hope it will help you.